# Custom object display in Dataset using MakeBoxes

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, dataset, boxes, object-oriented

The below code defines a couple "objects" in the Mathematica sense using a convention consisting of so-called Q-functions for creating types and data validation, `MakeBoxes` for formatting, `Association`'s for data, and `SubValues` for properties and methods. (It's a more of a convention than a framework and one I use often because it is not fussy and embraces Mathematica's symbolic paradigm.)

However, recently I have run into display issues of my custom formats within `Dataset`. Whenever I have an object like `SubObject` below it displays fine but when I have an on object like `Object` below which itself can contain a list of `SubObject`'s, the displaying of even a list of such `Object` objects results in `...` being displayed and notably this only seems to happen with an `Object` object contains a list of more than one `SubObject` objects.

Thank you ahead of time for any insights or fixes.

To test this out, plese just copy the below code and then run the subsequent tests to get the weird `Dataset` display issues. Here's my code to define the objects:

```
(*Utility q-function defining allowed rule pattern.*)
ClearAll[validRuleQ];
validRuleQ[(Rule | RuleDelayed)[_String, _]] := True;
validRuleQ[__] := False;

(*SubObject Data Q-Function*)
ClearAll[SubObjectDataQ];
SubObjectDataQ[
   Association["Name" -> _String, 
    "Date" -> _?DateObjectQ, ___?validRuleQ]] := True;
SubObjectDataQ[__] := False;

(*SubObject Q-Function*)
ClearAll[SubObjectQ];
SubObjectQ[SubObject[_?SubObjectDataQ]] := True;
SubObjectQ[__] := False;

(*SubObject*)
ClearAll[SubObject];

(*SubObject Format*)
SubObject /: 
  MakeBoxes[obj : SubObject[_?SubObjectDataQ], form : StandardForm] :=
   FrameBox[
   RowBox[{StyleBox[obj["Name"], Bold], " ", 
     StyleBox["(subobject)", Bold, Gray]}], RoundingRadius -> 5, 
   Background -> LightBlue];

(*SubObject Constructor*)
SubObject[name_String, date_?DateObjectQ, rules___?validRuleQ] := 
  SubObject[Association["Name" -> name, "Date" -> date, rules]];

(*SubObject Properties*)
SubObject[assoc_?SubObjectDataQ]["Association"] := assoc;
SubObject[assoc_?SubObjectDataQ]["Properties"] := Keys[assoc];
SubObject[assoc_?SubObjectDataQ][key_String] := Lookup[assoc, key];



(*Object Data Q-Function*)
ClearAll[ObjectDataQ];
ObjectDataQ[
   Association["Name" -> _String, "Date" -> _?DateObjectQ, 
    "Objects" -> {___?SubObjectQ}, ___?validRuleQ]] := True;
ObjectDataQ[__] := False;

(*Object Q-Function*)
ClearAll[ObjectQ];
ObjectQ[Object[_?ObjectDataQ]] := True;
ObjectQ[__] := False;

(*Object*)
ClearAll[Object];

(*Object  Format*)
Object /: 
  MakeBoxes[obj : Object[_?ObjectDataQ], form : StandardForm] := 
  FrameBox[RowBox[{StyleBox[obj["Name"], Bold], " ", 
     StyleBox["(object)", Bold, Gray]}], RoundingRadius -> 5, 
   Background -> LightBlue];

(*Object Constructor*)
Object[name_String, date_?DateObjectQ, objects : {___?SubObjectQ}, 
   rules___?validRuleQ] := 
  Object[Association["Name" -> name, "Date" -> date, 
    "Objects" -> objects, rules]];

(*Object Properties*)
Object[assoc_?ObjectDataQ]["Association"] := assoc;
Object[assoc_?ObjectDataQ]["Properties"] := Keys[assoc];
Object[assoc_?ObjectDataQ][key_String] := Lookup[assoc, key];
```

Here's the code to test the object definitions and see the output in a `Dataset`.

First, create some `SubObject` objects and their list variable with this code:

```
(*Create some SubObject objects and then put them in a list for later.*)
so1=SubObject["SubObject1",DateObject[]];
so2=SubObject["SubObject2",DateObject[]];
so3=SubObject["SubObject3",DateObject[]];
sobjs={so1,so2,so3}
```

This should display like this:

[image]

Now create the `Object` objects and their list with this code:

```
(*Create some Object objects and then put them in a list for later.*)
o1=Object["Object1",DateObject[],sobjs[[1;;1]]];
o2=Object["Object2",DateObject[],sobjs[[1;;2]]];
o3=Object["Object3",DateObject[],sobjs[[1;;3]]];
objs={o1,o2,o3}
```

This should display like this:

[image]

Now, simply display the `Dataset` for the `SubObject` object list:

```
(*Display SubObject Dataset*)
Dataset[sobjs]
```

Which displays as expected like so:

[image]

**Problem:**

And finally, the unexpected problem is here where the `...` displays instead of an `Object` object for any `Object` objects that contain more than one `SubObject` in a list, which in our case are the variables `o2` and `o3`. Here's the problematic code:

```
(*Problematic code for display of Object in Dataset*)
Dataset[objs]
```

Which displays as

[image]

How do I fix this so the `Object` objects display in `Dataset` correctly?

(Note: I have tried using HoldAll as an attribute on the constructor functions symbols, but this is not a desirable solution because then it's not convenient to script with the objects as any input variables to the constructors, such as a list of `SubObject`s into the constructor for `Object` won't be evaluated before insertion to the Association data.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from `` TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`smallQ ``, which is used to decide whether to display an item in full or whether to elide it with `…`:

```
TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`smallQ[e_] := 
  Or[SameQ[TypeSystem`PackageScope`$ElisionEnabled, False],
    TypeSystem`AtomicDataQ[e],
    And[Length@e <= TypeSystem`PackageScope`$ElisionLengthLimit,
        ByteCount@e <= TypeSystem`PackageScope`$ElisionByteLimit,
        LeafCount@e <= TypeSystem`PackageScope`$ElisionLeafLimit
    ]
   ];

TypeSystem`AtomicDataQ[x_] := Or[And[AtomQ[x], ! AssociationQ[x]],
    MemberQ[TypeSystem`$AtomicHeads, Head @ x],
    System`Private`ValidQ[x]
   ];
```

As you can see, the second and third object are determined to not be small:

```
TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`smallQ /@ objs
(* {True, False, False} *)
```

The definition of `smallQ` and `AtomicDataQ` also show a good solution for the issue: Simply add `Object` to `` TypeSystem`$AtomicHeads `` to tell the dataset rendering to treat `Object[...]` expressions similarly to `DateObject` etc:

```
AppendTo[TypeSystem`$AtomicHeads, Object];

TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`smallQ /@ objs
(* {True, True, True} *)

Dataset@objs
```

[image]